# Bootstrap used for device size 480 x 640 and 1600 x 900 having text size issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We are using the BOOTSTRAP to make our webpages run in two screen sizes. 480 x 640  and  1600 x 900 .

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/dz8492d4/][1] 


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/dz8492d4/
```

Using col-xs-* to size labels and texts. Which seems to work perfectly for the small screen , but the bigger screen is having a wider textbox.

BOOTSTRAP is new for the team. Is there way to handle this effectively using bootstrap? Or we need to override the default behavior of it?

Comment: have you set the base font-size and is it a relative or fixed value?  Are you using the precompiler versions (LESS/SCSS) or postcompiled?  Also, Which version of Bootstrap: 3 or 4?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I am using 3.3.7 Bootstrap version. I am using postcompiled BOOTSTRAP

Comment: It looks like it might be just a misunderstanding of how the columns work.  `col-xs-*` doesn't mean that the text field is always going to be small.  It means that at the `xs` resolution, it'll be `*` columns wide (usually out of 12).  You could have the class be `class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4"` making the text box smaller as you scale up. I might be misunderstanding the problem, however.

Comment: @JosephMarikle class="col-xs-* division of column as out primary goal was for the device 480 * 640 . How ever the web page loaded on the bigger screen as well should look similar. When I use class="col-sm-* the label and the text field wraps up. We want both the screen to look almost identicle. Using class="col-xs-* partially solves our problem, by keeping both the label and text field in a single row in both the devices. But the text-feild width is way lager in the bigger screen (using col-xs-*).

Comment: @JosephMarikle Were you able to see the fiddle code , which I have shared for the reference ?

Comment: Yes, I can see it.  Here's a fork of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/jd1z9abz/

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/fvzc6x/9

Comment: @JosephMarikle It was very helpfull. Thank you for guiding me through.